# Oracle: How to make package body inaccessible to user from viewing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

Is there a way to stop other users from viewing the package body, but can see package spec in Oracle? Other users can have execute privilige but no privilige to view package body.

Wrapping is not a solution as there are good number of unwrapt tools available. It doesn't serve the purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: wrap it https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/wrap-and-dbms_ddl-10gr2#:~:text=

Comment: ...and unwrap it back with https://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/

Comment: When you grant `EXECUTE` to a package then the user can only see the content  PACKAGE but not the PACKAGE BODY.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did the same. granted execute on an object of A to B. But B is still able to see package body in ALL_OBJECTS and also see package body. What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you, please, demonstrate it? Post SQL*Plus session which shows that user B sees package body and its contents (don't post actual code, only a few lines).